# How to redirect output to a text file in bash and have it show in the terminal at the same time?

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect, ansible

If I use the text re-directors `>` and `>>` they output to a text file which is fine for long term logging but, I also need them to be present on screen in the traditional Standard Input, Standard Output format as I'm running code through the shell (bash) function in Ansible.

Using `>>` makes Ansible believe it was a successful operation even if it failed which is undesirable.  Any help on how to achieve the having your cake and eating it too scenario?

Comment: @muru The duplicate you linked to doesn't answer how to use `>>` directly after the command and have the output on screen as well, which seems to be an essential part of the OP :-)

Comment: @Raffa why would `>>` be essential here?

Comment: @muru Can't say for sure ... Not my question ... but, "Using `>>` makes Ansible believe it was a successful operation even if it failed" is in the question anyway ...  I would suggest you ask the asker :-)

Comment: @Raffa Ok, but that sentence is followed by "which is **undesirable**" (bold mine), so if anything, *not* having `>>` seems to be better. (Though I think OP's somehow misunderstanding Ansible's operation here.)

Comment: @muru **"seems"** ... I couldn't agree more :-)

Answer (score 6):

**One way** is to pipe it to `tee -a /dev/tty >> file` like so:

```
echo "This is some text" | tee -a /dev/tty >> file
```

**Another way** is to pipe it to `tee -a file` with no redirects like so:

```
echo "This is some text" | tee -a file
```

**A third way**(if you need `>>` directly after the command) is to redirect to `/dev/tty`(not saved to file though) like so:

```
echo "This is some text" >> /dev/tty
```

**If that is not enough**, then you can use [**named pipes**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)(two terminals are needed for this process) by creating a named pipe called e.g. `my_pipe` in one terminal like so:

```
mkfifo my_pipe
```

Then, redirecting your output to it like so:

```
echo "This is some text" >> my_pipe
```

Then, from another terminal read that named pipe and do whatever you want with the output like so:

```
cat my_pipe | tee -a file
```

or like so(to keep the pipe waiting/open for reading between writes):

```
tail -F my_pipe | tee -a file
```

Keep in mind that paths apply to named pipes like any other file ... so make sure you provide the correct path to the named pipe when you use it.

Comment: `blah | tee file` will put the output into `file` and on stdout.

Comment: @doneal24 I know ... but, OP seems to need to use redirection `>` and `>>` ... so I am trying to give alternatives  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a suitable solution but am curious if there are better ways.

```
echo "Hello" >> file && cat file
```

Comment: this will `cat` the *entire* file, including whatever was there before you appended to it with `>>`

Comment: tail maybe a good substitute then.

Comment: *any* of the other answers that Raffa gave.